# Nifi container high cpu usage

Tags: linux, docker, cpu-usage, devops, apache-nifi

In my production environment i had a 8 core, around 40GB+ RAM server. I am seeing my docker containers were using more cpu cycles, and making other standalone deployed services slow.

Ex: we had a nifi service running in a container using cpu around 300%(varying one) and other containers like database, kafka some times.

here is the docker container inspect i found

```
      "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DiskQuota": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": 0,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
```

here is the top usage

```
$top
top - 01:08:47 up 15 days,  3:23,  1 user,  load average: 5.73, 5.58, 5.44
Tasks: 320 total,   4 running, 314 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu0  : 15.9 us,  6.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 77.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 26.8 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 69.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  8.9 us,  5.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 13.8 us,  6.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 78.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.4 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  : 34.4 us,  3.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 61.1 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  : 81.3 us,  4.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 11.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.5 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  : 64.8 us,  2.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 31.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.1 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  : 77.4 us,  5.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 16.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  57803616 total, 51826940 used,  5976676 free,  1047628 buffers
KiB Swap: 16773116 total,    77040 used, 16696076 free. 19288708 cached Mem
```

in general when we services running directly on server like web application which takes some amount of cpu and memory. will docker containers completely use the cpu cycle making other services slow?

if yes, then what would be the best process to make both services use resources properly by not making system heavily loaded?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Voted to close as this seems too broad of a question for this site (probably even for the sites linked by jww). As you mention production, perhaps the community of your support provider might be suitable.